# Preventing users from deleting records in one table that have related records in another table

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I have two tables that relate one-to-many in an Access database. The tables are:

```
tbluser : UserID [Primary Key]

tblproject : UserID [Foreign Key] , PrjID [Primary Key]
```

I need to prevent users from deleting any records in `tbluser` that have related records in the `tblproject` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Relationship in the Access database and select the "Enforce Referential Integrity" option:

[image: Relationship.png]

For detailed instructions on creating Relationships in Access, look here:

[Create, edit or delete a relationship](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-HA010072597.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Foreign Key Constraint defined on tblproject(UserID) referencing to tbluser(UserID) no user will be able to delete that user from tblproject anyway it will throw an error saying something along the lines`"Value referencing in tbluser".`